# Set default font in vega lite

Tags: vega-lite

Can I set a font, e.g. in [vega-lite's config object](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/config.html), that is used for all the labels and titles?

I currently set `labelFont` and `titleFont` for the x&y axis and the color legend, but it is the same font everywhere so it would be nice to set it just once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately no, there does not appear to be a global font setting in Vega-Lite. But you can set all fonts in the figure (for example to `"monospace"`) with the following config:

```
"config": {
  "axis": {"labelFont": "monospace", "titleFont": "monospace"},
  "legend": {"labelFont": "monospace", "titleFont": "monospace"},
  "header": {"labelFont": "monospace", "titleFont": "monospace"},
  "mark": {"font": "monospace"},
  "title": {"font": "monospace", "subtitleFont": "monospace"}
}
```

Alternatively, if you have control of the browser page where the chart is being rendered, you can set the default font for the `div` that the chart appears in using standard CSS.

Comment: Didn't think of simply setting it via CSS, thanks!
Setting it in the config section is also very concise and does not bloat my other definitions in the spec.

Comment: I'm trying to set the font via CSS but can't get it to work. I've set the font family on the div that i use for vegaEmbed: https://codepen.io/keckelt/pen/ZEYMmPg

Answer (score 1):

Checkout `config: fontConfig("monospace")`. I'm on vega-lite 4.5.1 and it's there.